# Stripe, subscription without trial days

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I created a plan with a billing period by month and a free trial of 30 days.

But on some cases, I would like not to offer the free trial.

So I create a Stripe Checkout Session with these options:

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
'customer_email' => 'email@email.com',
'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
'subscription_data' => [
    'items' => [[
        'plan' => $planId,
    ]],
    'trial_period_days' => false,
],
'success_url' => 'localhost/stripe-sucess/',
'cancel_url' => 'localhost/stripe-cancel/',
]);
```

But in the webhooks `checkout.session.completed` I see all the time `"trial_period_days": 30,`
I don't see any change when using the option `trial_period_days`.

Yet on 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data there is specified:

*subscription_data.trial_from_plan optional
Indicates if a plan’s trial_period_days should be applied to the subscription. Setting trial_end on subscription_data is preferred.
Defaults to false.*

How to remove the free trial days of a plan?

**NOTE**

The best is to create a plan without trial days and set the trial days with `subscription_data.trial_period_days`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the Plan's default trial period, you'd set `subscription_data.trial_from_plan: false`.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-trial_from_plan